# How get return value when using actor in akka-stream

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-stream

I am studying akka-stream at scala.
I want to get the value sent from the actor with code like this:

```
case class Message(value: String)

class LibraryService @Inject()(@Named("library-actor") library: ActorRef)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, ml: Materializer) {
  val sink = Sink.actorRef[Message](library, onCompleteMessage = "stream completed", onFailureMessage = (throwable: Throwable) => Fail(throwable.getMessage))
  val source = Source.single(Message("test"))

  def add(message: String): Unit = {
    val runnable = source to sink
    val value = runnable.run() // I want get "I receive 'test'"  at here.
    print(value) // This code prints "Not Used"
  }
}

class Library extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Message(message) => {
      sender ! s"I receive '$message'"
    }
  }
}
```

However, in the above code, only "Not Used" is output, and the value sent by the sender is not stored in'value'.
I want to get the value sent by the actor's 'sender'.
If you know anything, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sink.actorRef` materializes as `NotUsed`, meaning that it doesn't provide a useful value.  All it does is forward the messages to the target actor.

To get a response back, the best approach to this example is probably:

```
Source.single(Message("test"))
  .runWith(Sink.foreachAsync(1) { msg =>
    (library ? msg).map(println _)
  })
```

In general, if you're sending messages to an actor from a stream and expecting a response, `mapAsync` with an ask should be your first choice (`mapAsyncUnordered` for better throughput if and only if you don't care about preserving stream order).  If you're doing a `mapAsyncUnordered` and immediately passing the results to `Sink.foreach` to invoke a side effect, it's probably worth combining the ask with the side effect in a `Sink.foreachAsync` and removing the `mapAsyncUnordered`.

Editing to add: If you do care about ordering (hence using a `mapAsync` over `mapAsyncUnordered`), you can still use `Sink.foreachAsync`, but be sure to use single parallelism (i.e. `Sink.foreachAsync(1)`).  On the other hand, the advantage of `mapAsync` into `Sink.foreach` is that you can have parallelism be greater than one on the `mapAsync` and still preserve ordering for the side effect in the sink, e.g.:

```
/**
 * Transforms values from a source in parallel and applies a side 
 * effect to the transformed values. If value `a` is emitted before
 * value `b` by the source, the effects arising from `pureFutF(a)` 
 * will execute before the effects arising from `pureFutF(b)`.
 *
 * @param src
 * @param parallelism how many calls to pureFutF are in-flight at a 
 *  time
 * @param pureFutF asynchronous transformation; if parallelism is 
 *  greater than 1, order is not guaranteed, so ideally the order
 *  in which transformations are executed is not important
 * @param sideEffect
 * @return a future which successfully completes when the source has 
 *  completed and all side effects have been executed
 */
def runParallelStreamMap[A, B](src: Source[A, Any], parallelism: Int)
  ( pureFutF: A => Future[B], sideEffect: B => Unit): Future[Done] = {

  src.mapAsync(parallelism)(pureFutF).runWith(Sink.foreach(sideEffect))
}
```

It would be nice if there was a `.contramapAsync` method on a `Sink`.